# How to check for duplicate addresses in mapping

Tags: solidity, addresses, mapping

I want to have a mapping where it is only possible to add values when they are UNIQUE. It must not be possible to add duplicate keys, but I cannot get it working.

The code:

```
contract test {
    mapping(string => address) values;

    function AddValue(string randomValue) {
        require(values[randomValue] == 0x0);

        //execute transaction if randomValue doesn't exist
        //cancel transaction - payout if the randomValue exists 
    }
}
```

In this example I am trying to check whether the values[randomValue] is empty - doesn't exist. 
If it doesn't exist the code after may execute. If it DOES exist, the code must stop.
However, I am unable to find a solution.

Comment: Working fine for me.  You need to add a line like `values[randomValue] = 0x1;` (or whatever address) after the `require()` statement. Once you've done that it behaves exactly as you'd expect.

Comment: Thanks for reply :) 
& I do add msg.sender afterwards but left it out here. 
Also, I keep track of the length with a counter, which counts the length of the mapping. Everytime I add a randomValue that is already inside the mapping I get a metamask screen to confirm, I submit, it gets mined and the count increases. I have no idea what I am missing ;s ;s 
It seems like the require is doing nothing @benjaminion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've noticed in your example you use a `string` for key. Solidity uses the `keccack256(key)` as lookup value. So there's the case you have two different string mapping to the same value. (This is rare because it will mean you have found a collition of sha3).

If you have a mapping to a struct I'd use a boolean field to indicate an entry is used. An empty entry will such fields initially set to false.

```
struct Entry {
    bytes32 id;
    uint balance;
    bool used;
}

mapping (address => Entry) public collection;

function AddEntry(bytes32 _id, uint _balance) public {
    require(!collection[msg.sender].used);
    collection[msg.sender] = Entry(_id, _balance, true);
}
```

If you have a mapping to a value like address, you can check directly against an special value like `address(0)`.

```
mapping (bytes32 => address) public users;

function AddUser(bytes32 id) public {
    require(users[id] != address(0));
    users[id] = msg.sender;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) 
My problem was a malfunction with TestRPC or webpack (not sure yet, which of the two)
I have the frequent issue where the new or edited code does not seem to be compiled and pushed correctly. In this case, I just have to relaunch TestRPC, delete the build folder and compile - migrate the contracts again. 

However, this example remains a best practice on the issue I created :) +1